# Apache 2.4.16 on Mac El Capitan: how to make it work with TLS 1.2

Tags: apache, ssl, tls1.2

In my MacBook Pro I have Apache 2.4.16 with `OpenSSL 1.0.2d`.
I am trying to configure it with SSL and it should use also TLS 1.2.
So I created a self signed certificate with:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt`

and I wrote my `httpd-ssl.conf` file like the following:

```
###############################
######## Enable SSL ###########
<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
#SSLSessionCache shmcb:/Applications/AMPPS/apache/logs/ssl_gcache_data(512000) 
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
Mutex default
</IfModule>
###############################

#### Localhost SSL Entries ####
<IfModule ssl_module>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/lory/Sites"
  ServerName localhost
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCertificateFile "/Users/lory/Sites/localhost.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/lory/Sites/localhost.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

and if I perform `sudo apachectl start` it works. Anyway, ii I try on terminal:

`openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -tls1_2`

then this is what I get:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735258165328:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version   number:s3_pkt.c:362:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
  Protocol  : TLSv1.2
  Cipher    : 0000
  Session-ID: 
  Session-ID-ctx: 
  Master-Key: 
  Key-Arg   : None
  PSK identity: None
  PSK identity hint: None
  SRP username: None
  Start Time: 1451408861
  Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
  Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

from which I deduce that things don't work well.

In fact, if I check inside `phpinfo();` output I see:

- Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.5.30 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg as used version
- ssl, sslv3, sslv2

and more. I don't know why, I thought I had disabled them. 
How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

Special thanks to user  **Myles** for signaling this:

As of July 21, 2016, there is a pre-release available of MAMP PRO 4 which includes OpenSSL 1.0.2, get the pre-release here:

https://www.mamp.info/en/pre-release.html

Answer (score 0):

Do a `which openssl` from the terminal.  I think you'll find that it's not /usr/bin/openssl.  You're running an openssl that either you compiled or installed via HomeBrew or MacPorts.  The built-in Apache that comes with OS X can't use that openssl.  It'll use the one in /usr/bin, which is why `phpinfo()` reports 0.9.8zg.

Try `/usr/bin/openssl version` and you'll see the same 0.9.8zg.

Outside of compiling your own Apache or using one from HomeBrew or MacPorts, I don't think you can use a more modern openssl.